# how to do nginx rewrites from a url with get parameters

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-redirect

This is my first ever StackOverflow question so please bear with me.

Nginx serves many different sites for us and we have a lot of redirects from migrating clients from different vendors and such.  We have set up an /includes directory that houses redirect files for each domain that we migrate over.  Occasionally, we will need to write redirects from a url that contains get parameters:

```
http://example.com/content/default.aspx?NewsId=28
```

To do this, we have been doing this in an nginx /includes file called example.com-redirects

```
location ^~ /content/default.aspx {
    if ($args ~ "NewsId=28") { rewrite ^ http://example.com/news? permanent; break; }
    # add more statements like the one above
}
```

That has worked just fine for us thus far.  Unfortunately, we need to do the same thing but for a different domain that could have the same get parameters.  And of course nginx doesn't allow for duplicate locations.

```
location ^~ /content/default.aspx {
    if ($args ~ "NewsId=28") { rewrite ^ http://differentexample.org/news? permanent; break; }
}
```

I've tried a couple of different solutions all giving me syntax errors.  No one at my company is an nginx expert anymore so I could really use some help solving this.  I have added an `if ($host ~ "example.com")` within the location block and that gave me an error.  And I've tried adding the location block within the `if ($host ~ "example.com")` block.  Both times nginx told me that I can't put that there.

I usually find my answer in the vast knowledge base that is the internet but seem to be striking out on a solution for this and we're running out of time before we launch this client.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using if, use a variable. In the virtual host config you set this variable. In the include with the location you use it:

```
server {
    ...
    set $redirect_host "example.org";
    include /includes/news28.conf;
    ...
}

# include part
location /foo {
    if ($args ~ "NewsId=28") { rewrite $scheme://$redirect_host/news? permanent; }
}
```

Of course you need to set that variable also in the server config of the host already using this include. Hope this helps.